# Scalaz Lens to ReaderWriterState

Tags: scala, scalaz, lenses

Given, say

```
case class Person(age: Int)
val ageL: Lens[Person, Int] = ...
```

How do I come up with:

```
def incrementAge(by: Int): ReaderWriterState[Config, String, Person]
```

while taking advantage of `ageL` lens. The Scalaz Lens have some utilities to create a `State` out of a `Lens`, but I'm not sure how to convert that to a `ReaderWriterState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mods` method on the lens and `rwst` on the resulting state to write this pretty clearly:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type Config = Map[String, String]

case class Person(age: Int)
val ageL: Lens[Person, Int] = Lens.lensu(_ copy _, _.age)

def incrementAge(by: Int): ReaderWriterState[Config, String, Person, Int] =
  ageL.mods(_ + by).rwst[String, Config]
```

And then:

```
scala> incrementAge(1).run(Map.empty, Person(20))
res0: scalaz.Id.Id[(String, Int, Person)] = ("",21,Person(21))
```

This will return the incremented age, which seems like a reasonable thing to do, but if you only care about the change to the state, you could throw away the value with `ageL.mods_(_ + by)`.